# Seaborn plots clashes

Tags: python, seaborn

I tried to generate 2 plots using seaborn and the 2nd plot i got seemed to be overlaying the first plot

Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

sns.pairplot(iris)
plt.savefig("Pairplot")

sns.heatmap(iris.corr())
plt.savefig("heatmap")
```

Output

1st plot
[image]

2nd plot
[image]

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new figure prior to plotting the heatmap:

```
plt.figure()
sns.heatmap(iris.corr())
```